# Codeigniter how to not select duplicated id's

Tags: php, database, arrays, codeigniter

I've got a database and the fetched array looks something like this (if i was creating the arrays my self)

```
<?php

    $array[] = array('id' => 1, 'message' => 'test');
    $array[] = array('id' => 1, 'message' => 'test');
    $array[] = array('id' => 2, 'message' => 'test');
    $array[] = array('id' => 5, 'message' => 'test');
    $array[] = array('id' => 1, 'message' => 'test');
    $array[] = array('id' => 8, 'message' => 'test');
    $array[] = array('id' => 5, 'message' => 'test');
    $array[] = array('id' => 1, 'message' => 'test');

?>
```

As you can see, there is a few arrays with the ID 1, and i wanna select the last 5 items but if there is a duplicate, i wanna skip it, and move on. Is there any easy solution for this?

Comment: Can you show the db query .... perhaps need group by / distinct

Comment: Go to the source, change your query and have it select distinct (if possible). Otherwise you'll need to loop through it and drop the ones you don't want

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `Active Record Class`?

If so add this line to your query, before your get your results:

```
$this->db->distinct();
```

For current and future reference CI has and is praised for it's brilliant Documentation!
It is always worth taking a look there too:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

If you don't use the `Active Record Class`, do as suggested above :).

Answer (score 0):

you should use a query like this:

"SELECT DISTINCT id,message FROM your_table LIMIT 0,5"

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL Method:**
Reference this article @ w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(table.id),
  table.message
FROM
 db.messages
```

If you are adamant on doing this outside of the prefferred method of using MySQL you can use PHPS array_unique() function..

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
<?php 
  $result = array_unique($array);
  print_r($result);
```